# Cannot "apt upgrade" due initramfs error - "update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-86-generic with 1."

Tags: apt, kernel, btrfs, failed, initramfs

I have a Ubuntu 22.04 VM with CloudInit on a Proxmox Host which worked well, but recently I got often the issue after some time (some days, even after reinstalling) that I can't upgrade packages due to an initramfs error.

```
apt upgrade
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  gsasl-common libgsasl7 ruby-rack
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-86-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-86-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I searched on the internet but I couldn't find a valid solution.
On a recent host I tried a solution to remove the permissions from the hooks (btrfs,...) with `chmod -x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs`, which fixes the initramfs command and it "compiles" correctly, but after a reboot it ends up with not finding a "boot loader" or the initramfs.

I hope someone has finally a valid stable solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be experiencing issues with the initramfs update during package upgrades on your Ubuntu 22.04 VM, which is leading to boot problems. The error message suggests a problem with the `btrfs` hook during the `initramfs` update.
First, you should revert the change you made by removing the executable permission from the `btrfs` hook.

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs
```

Then try running the following commands to update and reconfigure `initramfs`.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

If the `initramfs-tools` package is still failing to configure, you might need to manually remove and reinstall it. First, remove the package.
Then, reinstall it.

```
sudo apt install initramfs-tools
```

Ensure that your system packages are in good shape by running.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

After making these changes, it's important to reboot your system to check if the initramfs issue is resolved.

```
sudo reboot
```

If the issue persists after following these steps, it's possible that there may be a deeper issue with your VM or the Proxmox host configuration. In that case, you might need to investigate further, possibly examining the Proxmox host logs.